# Is possible to use multiple conditions in list comprehension in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

trying to get a list of instances on AWS EC2 with tag 'Name' of an instance contain certain value.

This snippet is functional, but think we can make it cleaner :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import boto3

class proxies_on_ec2():
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      self.ec2client = boto3.resource('ec2')

   def get_list(self):
      self.get_all_instances = self.ec2client.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}])
    
      self.instances_list = []

      for instance in self.get_all_instances:
         for tag in instance.tags:
            if tag.get('Key') == 'Name':
               if "[Dev]" in tag['Value']:
                    self.instances_list.append({'Name': tag['Value'], 'id': instance.id, 'ip': instance.public_ip_address})

    return self.instances_list
```

I can't get the similar result with list comprehension :

```
self.instances_list = [{'Name':instance.tags[0].get('Value'), 'id':instance.id, 'ip':instance.public_ip_address} for instance in self.get_all_instances]
```

problem is instance.tags[0]. Is it possible to add 'if tag.get('Key') == 'Name' and replace instance.tags[0] to instance.tag after this condition ?

Thanks for help

Comment: A list comprehension essentially desugars to a regular for loop, so yes you can nest iterations & add conditions inside list comprehensions.

Comment: A list comprehension of that size won't be very readable. So, if you want a "cleaner" solution, that's probably not the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

```
self.instances_list = [
    {"Name": tag["Value"], "id": instance.id, "ip": instance.public_ip_address}
    for instance in self.get_all_instances
    for tag in instance.tags
    if tag.get("Key") == "Name" and "[Dev]" in tag["Value"]
]
```

Comment: I'd probably add an additional line break between the two for clauses, but other than this, neat ^^